# using if exist in mysql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

i have a mysql table with two date value **date** and **date2**

i need if date2 exist and if date2 > NOW() time  don't show the row
else show the row with date

if date2>NOW() ignore
if date2 is not exist or dates <= NOW() show

for example date=01/01/2020. and date2=01/01/2022

```
$db->query("select * from tbl_transaction where user_id='XXXX' and (if count(date2) from tbl_transaction where user_id='XXXX') > 0 ");
```

Anybody knows if it's possible to use IF in that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be case statement help you - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: *if date2 exist and if date2 > NOW() time* First condition is excess in this pair.